# Passing down all attributes in AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to pass all attributes down from a component instance to one of the elements in the component template?

For example, let's say I have a very simple component:

```
angular.module('...').component('customInput', {
  templateUrl: '<input ng-minlength="8">',
  controller: function () { },
  bindings: { }
});
```

Is there any way that I can do something like this:

```
<custom-input arbitrary-directive></custom-input>
```

and get back

```
<input ng-min-length="8" arbitrary-directive></input>
```

without specifying `arbitraryDirective` as a binding specifically? I just want to pass down all unspecified attributes to an inner element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I got was more imperative than declarative. It's also kind of hacky and brittle. So I'm not *terribly* happy about it, but it works.

In the controller, add a `$postLink` hook that looks something like this:

```
this.$postLink = function () {
  var input = $element.find('input'); // from the controller's second parameter, $element
  // copy directives and stuff over to inner input element
  angular.forEach($attrs, function (value, key) {
    if (key[0] === '$') {
      return;
    }

    var attr = $attrs.$attr[key];
    input.attr(attr, value);
  });
}
```